# Node JS is not installed on win machine

Tags: node.js

When I am trying to install node on win machine, I always get this error:

> ```
> An error occurred while applying security settings.
> Authenticated Users is not a valid user or group. This
> could be a problem with the package, or a problem
> connecting to a domain controller on the network. Check
> your network connection and click Retry, or Cancel to
> end the install.
> ```

What may be a reason and how it may be solved? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Havent you asked that yesterday? Where i comment? Is your machine in a domain/active directory or have you full admin rights on it?!

Comment: i asked this morning, but then removed it. Do not ask why) I can not answer on your first question about  'a domain/active directory'. How can i check it? About the second - yes, i am admin.

Comment: yesterday everything was ok, with node and so on. But then i wanted to create new angular project, that asked me to update node version. I started updating and as a result got this!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the Previous Version ([v14.17.1](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.1/node-v14.17.1-x64.msi)), worked for me.
The error seems to be related to non domain joined Computers with Admin User.

**Edit:**
The Version [v14.17.3](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.3/node-v14.17.3-x64.msi) seems to have a fix (stated in the node Gitlab Issue
[Install directory permissions broken on non-English Windows systems](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224))

Comment: any idea how to fix this for latest release?

Comment: The Bug is tracked on Github: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/39224

Comment: @Andrei Please update to the latest node Version and mark an Answer so other see at first glance that this Question is resolved

Answer (score 15):

Open Command Prompt (cmd.exe) as administrator and type:

```
net localgroup /add "Authenticated Users"
```

Then click the "Retry" button or run the installation file again.

Comment: Do you know why is this group missing? Is it safe to just dummy add it?

Answer (score 1):

Reason has been provided by @JIT Solution

To resolve: add the missing group.

1. Open the "Computer Management" tool
2. Open the "Local Users and Group" tree.
3. Open the "Groups" folder and search for a profile named "Authenticated Users", it should be missing.
4. Right-click on the Groups folder and select New Group. Type in "Authenticated Users" (case sensitive) as the New Group name and select Create.